# Java Manually convert Array to Node list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, nodes

So I have the following class and am trying to make a method where an array is converted to a node list. I tried a for loop but I can't get it through my mind trying to set the next for each value.

```
public class Node {
    public Node(int value, Node link) {
        data = value;
        next = link;
    }

    public void setData(int n) {
        data = n;
    }

    public void setNext(Node link) {
        next = link;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    private int data;
    private Node next;

    public Node arrayToList(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            Node n = new Node(a[i], //a[i+1] but it must be a Node, so how would you loop the next Node);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate the array in reverse order. Take care to save succ between iterations, and keep n ready for the final return.

```
public Node arrayToList(int[] a) {
  Node succ = null;
  Node n;
  for (int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    n = new Node(a[i], succ );
    succ = n;
  }
  return n;
}
```